# Defining the factorial of a real number

Tags: real-analysis

I'm curious, how is the factorial of a real number defined?  Intuitively, it should be:

$x! = 0$ if $x \leq 1$

$x! = \infty$ if $x >1$

Since it would be the product of all real numbers preceding it, however, when I plug $\pi!$ into my calculator, I get an actual value: $7.18808272898$

How is that value determined?

Comment: The Gamma Function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Gamma Function defined by
\begin{equation*}
\Gamma(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt
\end{equation*}
satisfies $\Gamma (n) = (n-1)!$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \geq 1$, so its an extension of the factorial to real and complex numbers.

Comment: Some theorems that suggest that the Gamma Function is the "right" extension of the factorial to the complex plane are [the Bohr–Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem) and [the Wielandt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wielandt_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

The [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is the generalization.  It is a function with a real argument with the property that $\Gamma(x+1)=x!$ whenever $x$ is a natural or zero.  It can also take complex arguments.  It is not defined on the non-positive integers, where it has poles.

Answer (score 2):

The [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), $\Gamma(x)$ can be represented by the integral

$$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt$$

for $x>0$.

Note that if $x=n$, where $n$ is an integer, then it is easy to show by integrating by parts that

$$\Gamma (n+1)=n!$$