# Factorials about decimals

Tags: factorial, gamma-function

How do you get the factorial of a decimal number using a pen and paper if it is possible?

Example: Find the factorial of $0.5!$

Comment: What do you call the factorial of a decimal number ? Do you refer to the $\Gamma$ function ? If yes you have to calculate the integral defined by $\Gamma$.

Comment: A quick google search of "factorial real number" lead to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975078/defining-the-factorial-of-a-real-number). So I think it's a duplicate

Comment: The other question asks for the definition; this question asks for methods of calculating numeric values with pen and paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't calculate $0.5!$ by hand. Decimal factorials do not make sense. The [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) might do what you want, but it's not the *easiest* to do by hand as it's a pretty unfriendly integral, at least in general. You might be able to calculate $\Gamma(1.5)$ (which would corespond to $0.5!$) by hand if you really wanted to:
$$
\Gamma(1.5) = \int_0^\infty \sqrt x e^{-x} dx
$$
and it turns out to be $\frac12\sqrt\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), but it won't work well for small numbers like $\frac12$.  For larger numbers, Stirling's approximation is quite good whether for integers or non-integers.  It says: $$n! \approx  \sqrt{2\pi n}\Bigl(\frac ne\Bigr)^n.$$

For example, $12.7!\approx 2.8616\times10^9$ and the Stirling formula gives around $2.843\times10^9$.

Of course, how to evaluate Stirling's formula with pencil and paper is an interesting question all by itself.

For smaller numbers of the form $n+\frac12$ your best bet is just to know that $$\frac12! = \frac12\sqrt\pi$$
and then use the rule that $(x+1)! = (x+1)x!$ so for example $\frac32! = \frac32\cdot \frac12! = \frac34\sqrt\pi$.

For numbers that are not half-integers, I have no good suggestions.  There may be something involving the [reciprocal factorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function) (that is, $x\mapsto \frac1{x!}$) that can be calculated with some accuracy.  There is a MacLaurin series that will be accurate, but it does not look easy to calculate with pen and paper.